# ReactJS + Flux - Store for Subcomponent data

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am building a dashboard for my site in ReactJs using the flux architecture.

Now let's say I have a *UsersComponent* which displays a list of all users registered in the website, and this component has a *UsersStore* where the data is fetched and stored.

Inside *UsersComponent* I render a sub component named *UsersStatsComponent* which is a small widget that displays statistics from the last 24 hours (number of new registrations, blocked users and more...) these statistics comes from a different API endpoint.

Where should I manage the data for this sub component?

**I consider my options are:**

1. Create another store named *UsersStatsStore* which fetches the data from the API and emits the change event to *UsersStatsComponent*.
2. Use the same store of *UsersStore* and create another action inside this store and emit a different event when the data has fetched from the API.

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is related to the User, I would recommend `UserStore`. 
But you need to make sure that there is not too much nesting in the store.

Comment: So the `UsersStore` will end up having 2 addListeners?
one for the list of users and one for the stats?
Is that sound a good practice? I haven't seen this approach in all the example & tutorials about flux stores.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26602976/5284640), you will get a more clarity when to use multiple stores.